# Firebase - addDoc() returns success even when no document was added

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

New to Firebase. I have a basic React form that takes a user's email and sends it to Firestore using addDoc().

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "@firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};
// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app)
```

```
const emailsCollectionRef = collection(db, "emails");

const addEmail = async (data: { email: string; }) => {
        console.log("Sending data to firebase");
    try {    
        const result =  await addDoc(emailsCollectionRef, {email: data!.email});
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", result.id);

    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
      }
        
    }
```

When I pass the user's input using addDoc() in a try catch I get this in the console

```
Sending data to firebase
Document written with ID:  YFPaCvSjeBssvUAtdqSh
```

Which is fine, but if I purposefully try to make it fail like for example changing the name of the collection in *emailsCollectionRef* e.g.

```
const emailsCollectionRef = collection(db, "NoSuchCollection");
```

and run the function again I get the same success message.

In the Firebase docs it says that addDoc()

> Returns:
>
> Promise<DocumentReference<T>>
>
> A Promise resolved with a DocumentReference pointing to the newly created document after it has been written to the backend (Note that it won't resolve while you're offline).

and under DocumentReference it says

> A DocumentReference refers to a document location in a Firestore database and can be used to write, read, or listen to the location. **The document at the referenced location may or may not exist**.

If I want to check if the write was succesful I have to ignore DocumentReference and immediately after using addDoc() do a separate query to see if that ID actually exists.

My question is, is there a better way to check if the write was actually succesful since DocumentReference obviously cannot be trusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections are created automatically when you write the first document to is, so quite likely your `addDoc` call with the non-existing collection actually *creates* that collection.

If you want to prevent that, you can only allow writes to specific, known collections in your database's [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), which are enforced on the server. At that point, the promise returns by `addDoc` will also reject/fail.

Comment: You're right, I had actually created a new separate collection. The new collection wasn't visible until I just refreshed the page which is what made me think no writes were actually happening. Thanks!